# Getting error with php artisan serve command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I have recently installed Laravel. Getting this error while entering this command:

```
php artisan serve
```

> Warning:
>   require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/php_ide/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/php_ide/bootstrap/autoload.php
>   on line 17 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/php_ide/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/php_ide/bootstrap/autoload.php
>   on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/php_ide/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/php_ide/bootstrap/autoload.php
>   on line 17 MacBooks-MacBook-Pro:php_ide macbookpro$

Comment: Can you share you project file structure?

Comment: make sure you had `vendor` directory in your project. on side note, also check whether `mod_ssl.so` commented out in **XAMPP >> Apache >> Config >> httpd.conf**. Nevertheless, you could start laravel with XAMPP by using it's Apache server.